# Using Group_by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

Using group_by today, trying to get my head around it and see if its the right solution for what I am trying to achieve. I have the following model

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :kickoff_time, :fixture_date
end
```

I want to group all the fixtures by fixture_date. So far my controller look like this

```
def fixturelist
  @fixtures = Fixture.all
  @fixture_date = @fixtures.group_by { |fd| fd.fixture_date }
end
```

What i would like to do then in my view is list the home_team and away team matches for that particular date

View

```
<% @fixture_date.each do |f| %>
 <%= f %>
<% end %>
```

This outputs an array of all the fixtures by date, so group_by has worked. Im looking for some pointers to get this working correctly, ie see all fixtures listed for each date. seeing a working example should help me understand some more

Example

```
Date

Team 1 Vs Team2
Team 1 Vs Team2
Team 1 Vs Team2

Date 2

Team 1 Vs Team2
Team 1 Vs Team2
Team 1 Vs Team2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month

I think you will want your view code to look like this,

```
<% @fixture_date.sort.each do |date, fixtures| %>
  <h2><%= date %></h2>

  <% fixtures.each do |fixture| %>
    <%= fixture.team_1 %> VS <%= fixture.team_2 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT:**

And if your `fixture_date` is a `datetime` column instead of just a `date` column, your controller code to look like this,

```
@fixture_date = @fixtures.group_by { |fd| fd.fixture_date.beginning_of_day }
```